# Intellij - how to force split on operator rather than on max size

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

How to tell intellij to split lines like Eclipse does:

```
    private static final boolean VERY_VERBOSE = !(System.getProperty( "veryverbose" ) == null
            || System.getProperty( "veryverbose" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "false" ));
```

and not like this:

```
    private static final boolean VERY_VERBOSE = !(System.getProperty( "veryverbose" ) == null || System.getProperty(
            "veryverbose" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "false" ));
```

That translates to if there is an operator prefer to split on it rather than truncate the line at maximum size

Notes:
• I have hard-limit set to 120 (And I prefer to keep it like that)
• I imported the eclipse preferences to Intellij but IJ still misbehave

I Use intelliJ ultimate 2023.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the following options under `Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces`:

- `Binary expressions` => `Wrap if long`
- `Binary expressions | Operation sign on next line` => `Enable`

Comment: Thank you, anyway that's how it is currently set but the behaviour is the one posted in the question

Comment: Please upload your [IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings) at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here. Probably some other Java code style setting interfere the formatting style

Comment: Here is the upload-id:
2023_07_17_PtdA5CjtT5ZKLZ4MPcWyZF

Comment: Try to switch `Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Method Call Arguments` from `Wrap if long` to `Do not wrap`